# C# object loses it's reference and becomes empty

Tags: c#, object, null

Here is the simplified code of my classes:

```
public class Game
{
    World world;
    DataManager dataManager;
    public Game()
    {
        world = new World();
        dataManager = new DataManager();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Menu mainMenu = new Menu(dataManager,world);
        //world = dataManager.LoadFile("Games\\test game.xml");
        //the commented line above is correcting my bug but I don't want
        //to do it that way.
        List <Location> locs = world.GetAllLocations();
        //when the debug mode arrives at this point, world is empty.
    }
}

public class Menu
{
    DataManager dataManager ;
    World world;
    public Menu(DataManager _dataManager, World _world)
    {
        this.dataManager = _dataManager;
        this.world = _world;
        world = dataManager.LoadFile("Games\\test game.xml");
        //the world is filled correctly here above.
    }
 }
```

Both classes are sharing the same namespace. 
My dataManager fill the world with an xml, which is perfectly working.
the world should be the reference from the game.world property but it seems to become empty as soon as we come back in the Game class...

I really don't understand while the program behave that way.
Here is the complete source if you need more:

https://github.com/mikyjax/TextAdventureGameEditor/tree/master/Text%20Adventure%20Engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how references work.

1. `new Menu(dataManager,world);` <= you call the constructor and pass in the `world` instance created in the constructor (*this is not the same as passing in a reference*).
2. `this.world = dataManager.LoadFile("Games\\test game.xml")` <= A new instance is created (so new pointer) and assigned to the local variable `world`. What does NOT happen is that the calling method in `run` now share the same `world` instance, that is still `null`.

If that is what you intended you must use the [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword (or `out`).

`public Menu(DataManager _dataManager, ref World _world)`

and call it with

`new Menu(dataManager,ref world);`

That said this is bad practice on 2 levels.

1. You should not have side effects in your constructor
2. If you are creating an object for use outside of the object (like in a factory) you should have a dedicated method just for that and then have that object returned as the return of the method.

---

```
public class Menu {
    DataManager dataManager ;
    World world;
    public Menu(DataManager _dataManager)
    {
        this.dataManager = _dataManager;
    }

    public World CreateWorld() {
        if(this.world == null)
            this.world = dataManager.LoadFile("Games\\test game.xml");
        return this.world;
    }
}


public class Game {
    World world;

    public void Run()
    {
        Menu mainMenu = new Menu(dataManager);
        this.world = mainMenu.CreateWorld();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, he doesn't pass a null reference. But you are right, he implicitely constructs a new world with LoadFile

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena - you are right, I missed the op creating an instance in the constructor. Like you said, it does not change the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

*Your* code makes something akin to:

```
A = B
A = C
```

and then you wonder why `B` is not `C` as well: you set the `Menu.World = _world` and then rewrite `Menu.Wold` to be what you load from the xml: `_world` is unmodified by it.

Why has the `Menu` constructor to populate the world at all - thats not really one its sole responsibility - is it?

I would rename your static `LoadFile` to `CreateWorld(..filename..)` and call that inside the `Run` method *before* creating the Menu. That way you can give the prepared `World` to the Menu constructor.

What I am still wondering about is, why ever a menu needs access to your raw world data ...

Comment: Although your answer is correct, the assignment to _world at the end of the method is now a no-op so should probably be removed.